# Any way to plot 100K+ points on a map?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

Does anyone know a way to upload hundreds of thousands of lat/longs to a map (Google Maps, but open to other suggestions) at the same time?

I have a CSV with the full address, and the lat/longs for each point.

I've been using Fusion Tables, but there are daily caps on this, plus it's not that intuitive.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing that in R?